# Не получается обьеденить переменные в строку

Tags: php, строки, phpexcel, int

Есть две переменных

```
$StringVariable = 'C';
$integerVariable = 1;
```

Почему когда я пишу так

```
'C'.$integerVariable
```

Всё работает, но вот таким способом не работает

```
$StringVariable . $integerVariable
```

Так библиотека PHPExcel показывает ошибку

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 
'Invalid cell coordinate C' in /profiles/...../PHPExcel/Cell.php:594 Stack 
trace: #0 /profiles/...../PHPExcel/Worksheet.php(1218): 
PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('C') #1 /profiles/...../PHPExcel
/Worksheet.php(1178): PHPExcel_Worksheet->createNewCell('C') #2 /profiles
/...../index.php(97): PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('C') #3 {main} thrown in 
/profiles/...../PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 594
```

Comment: Вероятнее всего у вас там __русская С__. Также `getCell('C')` как бы намекает - а число где?

Comment: Ну если мои глаза мне не врут, то я сделал всё правильно
$sheet->getCell($Column.$i)->getValue()
Где $Column строковая предопределённая переменная. Я тоже думал что на русском написал, но специально поменял на инглишь
А $i - числовая переменная

Comment: `(string)($StringVariable . $integerVariable)`

Comment: Ну как видите в `getCell` попадает только `C`. Так что надо выяснить где число. Возможно, вам следует отредактировать вопрос и добавить код который вызывает данную ошибку.